# Help with Points between rounds in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary

I am new to objective-c and am having trouble figuring out a way to store points for multiple players in my game. I have 4 characters in my game that are all objects from the same class. 1 is controlled by the user and the other 3 are controlled by the computer. Each level in my game consists of 3 races. I need a way to keep track of each characters finish place for each round so that at the end of the 3 races, I can award points to the user depending on which place they came in. Can anyone offer a suggestion? Would a NSDictionary accomplish this? I kind of have a very rough understanding of NSDictionary but wasn't sure if I could filter out each player's data to get just their data. In my mind, I think I need somewhere to store this data so then I can get the average of their finishes to compare to the other players.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why wouldn't you simply define an array which holds the players score for each level as an instance variable of the Player class? So for example:

```
@interface Player : NSObject {
NSArray *scoreForLevel;
}
```

Comment: Well at the end of each round I was hoping to show a summary of each players' placement. That I know would just be an array sorted by placement. I guess I could have 1 array to give the round summary and also store the scores in each player's object in another array.

I think you put me on the right track.